# WhatsHelp on Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0, widget

I need to know how to implements the WhatsHelp widget in Magento 1
This is the code:

```
<!-- WhatsHelp.io widget -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var options = {
            facebook: "#", // Facebook page ID
            whatsapp: "#", // WhatsApp number
            call_to_action: "Contact us", // Call to action
            button_color: "#E74339", // Color of button
            position: "right", // Position may be 'right' or 'left'
            order: "facebook,whatsapp", // Order of buttons
        };
        var proto = document.location.protocol, host = "whatshelp.io", url = proto + "//static." + host;
        var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = url + '/widget-send-button/js/init.js';
        s.onload = function () { WhWidgetSendButton.init(host, proto, options); };
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    })();
</script>
<!-- /WhatsHelp.io widget -->
```

The widget must appear on every page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set this code in Header or Footer `Miscellaneous Scripts` field, via backend configuration :

`System > Configuration > Design > Footer`

Comment: How can i send my EventObserver log message by whatsapp message? @DependencyHell

Comment: You should check the official Whatsapp api documentation, you may need an account https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/getting-started/